# Image and label not aligning correct

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, label

I am trying to align the text of the label so it starts at the same indent as the text in the first line when the text spills over into the next line due to insufficent screen space. I created this example to demonstrate the problem im having.

Alignment should be like this

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/74k8kptc/2/

```
<body>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="toggle_head">
            <img src="pfeil_rechts_blau.png" alt="Expand" class="expand">
            <img src="pfeil_links_blau.png" alt="Collapse" class="collapse">
            <label class="Question">Some long text that doesnt align properly when the page forces text on new line on making it smaller</label>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle_body">
            <hr>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.toggle_body {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size:12;
    display: none;
}
.Container {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.Expand {
    height: 8px;
}
.Collapse {
    height: 8px;
}
.Question {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```js
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();

$(".toggle_head").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle(500, function () {
        $this.children('img').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: now check to this it's easily http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/74k8kptc/7/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tinuyavafe/edit?html,css,output - a css way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.toggle_body {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size:12;
    display: none;
}
.toggle_head {
        display: table;
}
.Container {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.Expand {
    height: 8px;
}
.Collapse {
    height: 8px;
}
.Question {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
img{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74k8kptc/5/

Comment: Thanks, thats the one

Answer (score 1):

```
.Question {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Do I understand what you want to do ? Just align question and text ?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/74k8kptc/4/

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt do a very good job explaining, but i want the text of the label to start next to the image, and if any text of the label spills into the next line, i want that text to start at the same indent position as the text in line one.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to this way**

```
   .toggle_head {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.toggle_head img {
   display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.Question{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/74k8kptc/7/)**

Comment: Also works well thanks, will need to see which solution fits better for my expander